# Pandas passing wrong dtypes when calling apply

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running into an issue using the `pandas.DataFrame.apply` function.

It seems to cast all values to `bool`, unless I "touch" the `DataFrame` by adding a new column. This happens regardless of whether I use row or column-based `apply` (i.e. `axis=0` or `axis=1`).

My intuition tells me I'm doing something deeply wrong here, but I can't put my finger on what the problem is.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

start_date = datetime(2014, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime(2014, 1, 3)

events = pd.DataFrame({
    "some_boolean_field": True,
    "timestamp": pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D')
})

def do_stuff(event):
    print event
    print ""

def run_experiment(message, df):
    print message
    print "**********************************"
    print df
    print df.dtypes
    df.apply(do_stuff, axis=1)
    print "\n\n"

run_experiment("BEFORE ADDING EXTRA FIELD", events)

events['foo'] = "WTF"  # Insane hack to get pandas to pass the correct row dtypes when applying the `do_stuff` function.
run_experiment("AFTER ADDING EXTRA FIELD", events)
```

This outputs:

```
BEFORE ADDING EXTRA FIELD
**********************************
  some_boolean_field  timestamp
0               True 2014-01-01
1               True 2014-01-02
2               True 2014-01-03
some_boolean_field              bool
timestamp             datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
some_boolean_field    True
timestamp             True
Name: 0, dtype: bool

some_boolean_field    True
timestamp             True
Name: 1, dtype: bool

some_boolean_field    True
timestamp             True
Name: 2, dtype: bool




AFTER ADDING EXTRA FIELD
**********************************
  some_boolean_field  timestamp  foo
0               True 2014-01-01  WTF
1               True 2014-01-02  WTF
2               True 2014-01-03  WTF
some_boolean_field              bool
timestamp             datetime64[ns]
foo                           object
dtype: object
some_boolean_field                   True
timestamp             2014-01-01 00:00:00
foo                                   WTF
Name: 0, dtype: object

some_boolean_field                   True
timestamp             2014-01-02 00:00:00
foo                                   WTF
Name: 1, dtype: object

some_boolean_field                   True
timestamp             2014-01-03 00:00:00
foo                                   WTF
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

- pandas version: 0.14.1
- numpy version: 1.8.1
- Operating System: Mac OS X 10.9.5

Comment: This is fixed in 0.15.0 (I remember fixing, but can't find the specific reference), here is the rc http://pandas.pydata.org/;  0.15.0 release is imminent in any event.

Comment: This exact same issue arises with `DataFrame.iterrows`. Not sure if that's also fixed as part of 0.15.0, but it's something to watch out for. My workaround "fixes" things in both cases.